# What of a multi-dimensional array

Tags: react-native

What if the I want to filter from both the outer and inner array like below. Because i also have a multi-dimensional array where the i want to filter from both the outer and the inner array. The dataBackUp is the outer array while the v.data is the inner array. Please help me with this too, thanks.

```
this.state.dataBackUp.filter(v => (               
      v.title.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase()) ? filtered.push({title: v.title, data: v.data})
      : 
      v.data.filter(i => (
        i.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase()) ? filtered.push({title: v.title, data: [i]}) : ''
      ))        
    ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
filtered = this.state.dataBackUp.filter(item => 
               item.title.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase) || 
               item.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())
              )
```

Comment: Thanks, i was able to use this OR method to fix my problem. :)